# custom hash generated password and module wise added db password is different?

Tags: 8, hooks

```
function custom_submit_method(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {    

  $cusers = $form_state->getValue(array('name'));
  $cpass = $form_state->getValue(array('pass'));



  $gh = new \Drupal\Core\Password\PhpassHashedPassword();
  $hash_password = $gh->hash($cpass);
  $check_pass = $gh->check($cpass, $hash_password);


  //  \Drupal::logger(' customusersubmit')->notice('customusersubmit submit ') ;


 //  login_finalize($cusers, $cpass);


   drupal_set_message($hash_password .'------------'. $check_pass);      
 }

Output : $S$5JdG.BjCPSTzc03AJ7aYPwMMH6HR.63IDUzqG3h2kkjG0NEcXtIo------------1 for admin

 Admin Password: $S$EnLPNV41YaHAPKhzwTGHVIir.OlOyK9ngYyEzVKdsd//WMnlaegV
```

When on comparing to db admin password the hash generated salt value is    different. It timely change for every runtime.

Kindly suggest me the Idea.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is correct: The password is always salted with a different string.

If you want to verify a password, don't hash it, just check it against the value that was stored, that *does* work.

You're probably asking the wrong question. Explain what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: On user login without SSL. To avoid the Plain text passing in POST parameter, i am generating with (pass + hash + salt + session) and make compare with (DB + session) make login to website.

Answer (score 1):

As Berdir said, if you call `\Drupal\Core\Password\PhpassHashedPassword::hash()`, you will get a different result each time. That is normal: Saving the same password more than once should give a different result each time. This doesn't allow to notice if there are users using the same password, and this is better for security. In the case they get the password of one of the users, and they are able to read the database, they would not find out so easily every user using the same password.

The code you are showing is not the code you should use. To verify the given password for a user is correct, you should use the [user.auth](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21UserAuth.php/class/UserAuth/8.2.x) service. [`UserAuth::authenticate()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21UserAuth.php/function/UserAuth%3A%3Aauthenticate/8.2.x) gets the username and password, and it returns the user ID, if there is a user with that username and the password is correct, or `FALSE`.
[`UserLoginForm::validateAuthentication()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21Form%21UserLoginForm.php/function/UserLoginForm%3A%3AvalidateAuthentication/8.2.x), one of the validation methods used from the login form, uses that service.

Notice that the [`\Drupal\Core\Password\PhpassHashedPassword`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Password%21PhpassHashedPassword.php/class/PhpassHashedPassword/8.2.x) class is a class implementing a service. You should not create an object of that class directly, but invoke it as service or, rather better, invoke the *user.auth* service which uses it.